Git - maintain version control for only specific folders in two branches
I have a Git repo with master branch and a preprod branch that has only a few folders in it from master. I want to setup automation to create a PR once a day for preprod to merge to master. What Git commands can I use to ensure that I only pull changes to certain folders from master and push changes to them from preprod? Right now if I create a PR from preprod to master it shows all the files from master too that I don't need.

Where did you create the PR? In Azure DevOps or local command line?

When we create the Pull Request to merge branch changes in Azure DevOps, all changed files will be identified as changes between branches, and we cannot exclude these files.
Here is a suggestion ticket with the same requirement: Ignore Files when creating Pull Request
For a workaround, you can use the git command: git merge --no-commit --no-ff preprod. Then you can customize the contents of the merge commit. Finally, you can run git commit to push the changes to master branch.
Here is an example:
git clone -b master repourl
git merge --no-commit --no-ff preprod
git reset -- /path/to/folder1
git checkout -- /path/to/folder1
git reset -- /path/to/folder2
git checkout -- /path/to/folder2
git commit -m "Merge from preprod to master"
git push

We can integrate git commands into Azure Pipelines to achieve automation.
